# I don't know why I can't initialize an array of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, aggregate-initialization

I have this piece of code in C++:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements = {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}};
```

and it says: error: excess elements in struct initializer

I don't know why that happens. If I write that it works:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements = {{1,2}};
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is subtle in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization); it expects on more braces for the subobject (underlying array).

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements = {{{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}}};
//                                           ^                         ^ <- for std::array
//                                            ^                       ^  <- for underlying array
```

You got the error for the initializer `{{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}}` because there're 4 `{1,2}`s to initialize the subobject (underlying array) but `std::array` has only one, i.e. excess elements.

Answer (score 2):

To initialize an `std::array` object you need *two* curly-brace pairs: The outer curly-braces is for the object itself, and the inner is for the array.

That means your initialization needs to look like

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements = {{{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples how you can initialize an object of the type you are using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() 
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements1 = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements2 = { { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 } };
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements3 = 
    { 
        { 
            { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2 }
        }           
    };
    
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements4 = 
    { 
        { 
            { { 1, 2 } }, { { 1, 2 } }, { { 1, 2 } }, { { 1, 2 } }
        }           
    };
    
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> elements5 = 
    { 
        {
            { 1, 2 }, 1, 2, 1, 2, { 1, 2 }
        }           
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to the following quote from the C++ 17 Standard (11.6.1 Aggregates)

> 12 Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows. If the
> initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding
> comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the elements
> of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more
> initializer-clauses than elements. If, however, the initializer-list
> for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough
> initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the elements
> of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are left to
> initialize the next element of the aggregate of which the current
> subaggregate is an element.

`std::array` is defined as an aggregate that contains another aggregate.

Here is a demonstrative program to make the quote more clear that shows an initialization of a two-dimensional array

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 4, N = 4;
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        5, 6, 7, 8,
        { 8, 7, 6, 5 },
        4, 3, 2, 1,
    };
    
    return 0;
}
```

You may imagine the representation of the type `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4 >` as a declaration of the structure B in the following demonstrative porgram.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a[2];
};

struct B
{
    A b[4];
};

int main() 
{
    B b1 = 
    {
        
    };
    
    B b2 =
    {
        {
        }
    };      

    B b3 =
    {
        {
            {
            }
        }
    };      

    B b4 =
    {
        {
            {
                { {}, {} }
            }
        }
    };      

    return 0;
}
```

Investigate the program.

Comment: I don't understand why your code works. It is an array of arrays, every element of the array is an array and it is represented by {}.

Comment: @MartíSerra See the quote from the C++ 17 Standard provided in my answer.